# Python logs not appearing in Google Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

[image]I am not able to see Logging messages created in my python code when dataflow jobs are running. I have followed the documentation but no logs are appearing!

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging

I have imported 'logging' and even created a custom logger as per the below:

```
    logger = logging.getLogger('TEST_LOGGER')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

The below is an extracted function where I have input a number of logs and print statements, just to try and see any sort of output in the Dataflow UI:

```
    def check_file_size(file):
        file = 'gs://Redacted'
        file_size = gcsio.GcsIO.size(file) 
        print('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
        logger.info('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
        logger.info(f'file_size..... - {file_size}')

        if(file_size <= 4):
                print('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
                logger.info('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
                        
                raise Exception("ERROR IN FILE")
        else:
                print('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
                logger.info('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
                return file_size
```

None of the above messages are shown in the UI, in fact no custom log messages are shown...

I would expect the logs to be shown both under 'worker logs' and also on the individual step logs for that function. I am really running out of ideas as to why these logs are not appearing -n any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May you share the Dataflow pipeline code please ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun - Hi - I have added as an image to the post as code was too long to post in comment. Let me know for any clarification

Comment: Hi @Ryank12345, is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

If you import `logging` in the following way, it should work :

```py
import logging

def check_file_size(file):
        file = 'gs://Redacted'
        file_size = gcsio.GcsIO.size(file) 
        print('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
        logging.info('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
        logging.info(f'file_size..... - {file_size}')

        if(file_size <= 4):
                print('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
                logging.info('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
                        
                raise Exception("ERROR IN FILE")
        else:
                print('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
                logging.info('FILE SIZE:' + file_size)
                return file_size
```

In this case, the logs should appear in the `Dataflow` UI steps and also in `Cloud Logging`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already imported logging as you have stated and yet the logs are still not appearing!

Comment: Which version of Beam are you using ?

Comment: Apache Beam Python 3.7 SDK 2.38.0

Comment: It's weird, it works for me :(, when I previously used your version it worked and it also works with Beam `2.43.0`.

Comment: This works for me too. It's possible you don't have logging because you don't have any elements. Maybe try something simple like `p | beam.Create([1, 2, 3]) | beam.Map(logging.error)`?